# Athena Query Queuing Time: What affects it?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-athena

I've started using Athena recently and it appears useful. However, one thing that bugs me is that Query Queuing times can sometimes be very long (around a minute). At other times, queries are executed almost immediately.

I have not been able to identify reasons why queries sometimes queue for so long, and not at other times. The only thing I noticed is that Table Creation and other DDL statements don't queue for long.

What are the factors that affect queuing time? Server load? Query length? Query complexity?

How can I reduce queuing time? There's no information on this available in the documents as far as I'm aware.

Comment: I don't think there is anything you can do about it. You may try to contact AWS support but that will be it. I could be wrong but I have not come across anything that indicates we have control over it. Here is what it says: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/athena/latest/ug/release-note-2018-05-17.html

Comment: @Asdfg Unfortunately I don't have the required support status to ask questions like that. It'd be nice if there was some indication on how long queries are queueing. How are others dealing with the wait? Here's the excerpt from the doc you quoted: After you submit your queries to Athena, it processes the queries by assigning resources based on the overall service load and the amount of incoming requests. We continuously monitor and make adjustments to the service so that your queries process as fast as possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Around a minute it's not that long. We had a few weeks during which we had a random queuing time up to 10m. After a lot of back-and-forth with the support they finally tweaked something and queuing time was reduced to up to 1m, with average 10s.
The queuing is unrelated to your specific query or even "max concurrent queries" settings on your account, it's related to global region Athena load and many other hidden settings that AWS engineers can tweak.

Comment: Thanks, that's kind of what I figured out. Good to hear though that getting in touch with support helped.
Whether a minute is too much depends on usage. I was just wondering whether there's anything that can be done.